# Knowing Onclick Event fired

Tags: delphi, events, onclick

I use a server client component, and when a file is being received in the TransferFile event of this component, I use an alert message component. So I want, if the user clicks on the alert message, the program to continue executing code in the TransferFile event to accept the file transfer in case the button is clicked, or to exit the procedure when not.
pls see bellow code:

```
procedure TfrmReadFile.ServerReceiveEvent(Sender: TObject;
  Client: TSimpleTCPClient; Event: TTOOCSEvent);
begin
  if (Event is TTOOCSEventFileTransfert) then
  begin
    Alert.Show;
      if Alert.OnAlertClick then
      begin
        with (Event as TTOOCSEventFileTransfert) do
        if (dlgSaveFile.Execute) then
          with TMemoryStream.Create do
            try
              Write(Content[1], Length(Content));
              SaveToFile(dlgSaveFile.FileName);
            finally
              Free;
            end;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

but "if Alert.OnAlertClick then" is wrong

```
procedure TfrmReadFile.AlertAlertClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;
```

Please help me for these codes.

the AlertMessage is one of the TMS component and it hasn't ShowModal but it has Alert.Show Procedure that I use. and I want to pause the executing code untill the alert show time is finish and if user not click on alert executing the code aborted and no file saved.

Comment: You need to tell us what this alert component is. Do you want to keep executing the TCP code whilst the dialog shows? Is the dialog modal? The question is still very hard to understand. You must edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: Alert.ShowModal; If Alert.Modalresult=mrOk then... would be something you intened, but a ReceiveEvent will occure more then on time. A Flag set before would be a better solution.

Comment: You need a state machine to implement your program logic. The events of the components you use should call a method that changes the state of a state machine, and all actual work should be implemented as the state machine method(s).

Comment: Dear Serg pls describe more. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code it's obvious that by the time you get to show the Alert, **the file transfer already occurred**: it's only a matter of **"Do I save to file"** or **"Do I discard the content I already received"**. I'm inferring this information from your use of the `TMemoryStream.Write()` - that function takes a buffer as a parameter, so I assume the `Content[1]` gives your the buffer. This also means the `Content` is allready populated with the data you need. Too late to NOT transfer it, it's already in memory, all you can do is save it to disk or discard it.

I also have no idea how TMS's Alert works, but I'm going to assume only one Alert can be shown at any given time, and I'm going to assume you dropped your `Alert` on a component (ie: There's only one Alert in the whole program).

You should first alter the code for your "received event" to immediately move the content to a `TMemoryStream`. Also make sure you don't get into trouble with recursive re-entrance. Add a private field to your form, call it `FLastContentReceived: TMemoryStream`; Now alter your code to look like this:

```
procedure TfrmReadFile.ServerReceiveEvent(Sender: TObject;
  Client: TSimpleTCPClient; Event: TTOOCSEvent);
begin
  if (Event is TTOOCSEventFileTransfert) then
  begin
    // Re-entry before we managed to handle the previous received file?
    if Assigned(FLastContentReceived) then
      raise Exception.Create('Recursive re-entry not supported.');

    // No re-entry, let's save the content we received so we can save it to file
    // if the user clicks the Alert button.
    FLastContentReceived := TMemoryStream.Create;

    // I don't know what Content is, but you've got that in your code so I
    // assume this will work:
    FLastContentReceived.Write(Content[1], Length(Content); 

    // Show the alert; If the OnAlertClick event fires we'll have the received file content
    // in the FLastContentRecevied and we'll use that to save the file.
    Alert.Show;
  end;
end;
```

You're trying to do an if on `Alert.OnAlertClick` - so I assume there's an event in your `Alert` component that's called `OnAlertClick`. Write this in it's event handler:

```
procedure TfrmReadFile.AlertAlertClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not Assigned(FLastContentReceived) then raise Exception.Create('Bug');
  try
    if dlgSaveFile.Execute then
      FLastContentReceived.SaveToFile(dlgSaveFile.FileName);
  finally FreeAndNil(FLastContentReceived);
  end;
end;
```

You'd also need a way to discard the `FLastContentReceived` if the form is closed before the Alert button gets clicked OR there's a time-out (the Alert goes away without the user clicking it). The first job (getting rid of FLastContentReceived) when the form is closed is simle: add this to your form's `OnDestroy`:

```
FLastContentRecevid;Free;
```

Handling the timeout might a bit more difficult. If the `Alert` has an event that's called when the alert times out and the Balloon goes away without being clicked then use that event handler to do this:

```
FreeAndNil(FLastContentRecevid);
```

If it offers no such thing you could set up a `TTimer` for an interval equal to the timeout of the alert (or slightly longer to be safe), enable it before showing the alert and do this from it's `OnTimer`:

```
procedure TFrmReadFile.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  FreeAndNil(FLastContentRecevid);
end;
```

Comment: Dear Cosmin, I won't to check content I want if user click on the alertmessage file transfer done else reject transfer file.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're saying, but I guess it revolves around "reject transfer file". Well, look at your code: You've *already* received the file when your ServerReceiveEvent event is invoked: the content is *already* locally available in your `Content` field. You can't NOT receive it, all you can do is save it to file or discard it.

Comment: I edited the answer to clarify why I assume the file transfer already took place by the time your `ServerReceiveEvent` is called. Too late to REJECT it, all you can do is DISCARD it.